# VBA - Submit selected value from dropdown box

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I am looking for a way to select a certain option from a drop down list. I am able to highlight the value that I want but I am not able to activate it. Instead, the option from the list just becomes blue. I also cannot click on anything else anymore.

The second drop down list also does not appear as it depends on the option chosen in the first drop down list.

Can anybody point me in the right direction? I assume that I have to submit or activate my choice? But I've been trying multiple different things that I found googling but none seem to work.

Here is my VBA code:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://www.2dehands.be/plaats/"


While IE.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend


IE.document.getElementById("manual-option").Click


Set Title = IE.document.getElementById("level1-option")
Title.selectedIndex = 5


IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
```

And here is the HTML code:

```
 <div class="categories-wrapper-wrapper">
  <div class="suggestion-wrapper">
    <div class="custom-radio">
      <input  type="radio" name="suggestion" id="manual-option" class="manual-option" value="manual-option" />
      <label for="manual-option">
        Manueel selecteren
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="categories-wrapper  ">
    <div class="custom-select" data-custom-select>
      <label for="level1-option" class="has-hidden-label">Afdeling</label>
      <span class="btn-select icon-down_thin">Kies afdeling</span>
      <select class="categories-options" data-level="1" name="level1-option" id="level1-option" >
        <option value="">Kies afdeling</option>
        <option value="kunstantiek" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/kunstantiek/">Antiek &amp; Art</option>
        <option value="audiovideo" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/audiovideo/">Audio, Video &amp; TV</option>
        <option value="auto-onderd-access" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/auto-onderd-access/">Auto-onderdelen</option>
        <option value="auto" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/auto/">Auto's</option>
        <option value="beauty" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/beauty/">Beauty &amp; Gezondheid</option>
        <option value="auto-bedrijf" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/auto-bedrijf/">Bestelwagens &amp; Vrachtwagens</option>
        <option value="sieraden" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/sieraden/">Bijoux &amp; Horloges</option>
        <option value="boek" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/boek/">Boeken &amp; Strips</option>
        <option value="boten" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/boten/">Boten</option>
        <option value="brommerscooter" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/brommerscooter/">Brommers &amp; Scooters</option>
        <option value="kantoor" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/kantoor/">Business &amp; Industrie</option>
        <option value="kamperen" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/kamperen/">Caravans &amp; Kamperen</option>
        <option value="cd" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/cd/">CD &amp; Vinyl</option>
        <option value="computer" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/computer/">Computer &amp; Game Consoles</option>
        <option value="dieren" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/dieren/">Dieren &amp; Toebehoren</option>
        <option value="doe-het-zelf-bouw" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/doe-het-zelf-bouw/">Doe-het-zelf &amp; Bouw</option>
        <option value="witgoed" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/witgoed/">Elektronische apparatuur</option>
        <option value="fiets" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/fiets/">Fietsen</option>
        <option value="films-tv-series" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/films-tv-series/">Films &amp; TV-series</option>
        <option value="foto" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/foto/">Foto &amp; Camera</option>
        <option value="vrijetijd" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/vrijetijd/">Hobby</option>
        <option value="meubel" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/meubel/">Huis &amp; Meubelen</option>
        <option value="huis" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/huis/">Immo</option>
        <option value="werk" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/werk/">Jobs &amp; Diensten</option>
        <option value="keuken" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/keuken/">Keuken</option>
        <option value="kids" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/kids/">Kinderen &amp; Baby's</option>
        <option value="kleding" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/kleding/">Kleding &amp; Accessoires</option>
        <option value="landbouw" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/landbouw/">Landbouw &amp; Tuinbouw</option>
        <option value="motor" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/motor/">Motoren</option>
        <option value="muziek" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/muziek/">Muziek</option>
        <option value="overig" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/overig/">Overig</option>
        <option value="paardensport" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/paardensport/">Paardensport</option>
        <option value="revalidatie" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/revalidatie/">Revalidatie &amp; Zorg</option>
        <option value="speelgoed" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/speelgoed/">Speelgoed &amp; Spelletjes</option>
        <option value="sport" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/sport/">Sport &amp; Fitness</option>
        <option value="studie" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/studie/">Studeren</option>
        <option value="telecom" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/telecom/">Telecommunicatie</option>
        <option value="tuin" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/tuin/">Tuin</option>
        <option value="vakantie-toerisme" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/vakantie-toerisme/">Vakantie &amp; Toerisme</option>
        <option value="verzamel" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/verzamel/">Verzamelen</option>
        <option value="zendamateur" 
                data-href="/callback/discovery/zendamateur/">Zendamateur</option>
      </select>
      <button type="submit" class="category-submit ui-button-secondary " >Selecteer</button>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-select is-disabled" data-custom-select>
      <label for="level2-option" class="has-hidden-label">Rubriek</label>
      <span class="btn-select icon-down_thin">Kies rubriek</span>
      <select class="categories-options" data-level="2" name="level2-option" id="level2-option"  disabled="disabled" >
        <option value="">Kies rubriek</option>
      </select>
      <button type="submit" class="category-submit ui-button-secondary is-hidden"  disabled="disabled" >Selecteer</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is a good new contributor post in my opinion +

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Internet Explorer:**

Looking at the event listeners for that `select` element it monitors an `change` event. If you add and trigger that it works

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub MakeSelection()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.2dehands.be/plaats/"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .document.querySelector(".icon-radiobutton").Click

        Dim event_onChange As Object
        Set event_onChange = .document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
        event_onChange.initEvent "change", True, False

        With .document.querySelector("#level1-option")
            .selectedIndex = 2
            .FireEvent "onchange"
            .dispatchEvent event_onChange
        End With
        Stop
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Selenium Basic:**

I would consider using [selenium basic](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/tag/v2.0.9.0) for vba. After installing ensure the ChromeDriver.exe is in the selenium folder and go to VBE > Tools > References > Add a reference to selenium type library.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub MakeSelection()
    Dim d As WebDriver
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const url = "https://www.2dehands.be/plaats/"
    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get url
        .FindElementByCss("button[data-consent-all]").Click
        .FindElementByCss(".icon-radiobutton").Click
        .FindElementById("level1-option").AsSelect.SelectByText "Antiek & Art"
        Stop

        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```